# Change back ground colour of a text box on mouse over

Tags: javascript, css

I hava a text box . Now on mouse over , blue color shows. But actually i dont want color change on mouse over. Can any one give me css style for this...

Comment: show some code...or give a fiddle

Comment: try with this one... input:hover{background:transparent !important;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty general and ambiguous question but if I understand you correctly try this

```
textarea:hover, input[type="text"]:hover {
background: #ffffff;
}
```

In case you mean on focus replace hover with focus and change #ffffff to the color you want